# How to string concatenation inside of EJS for loop?

Tags: node.js, ejs

Looping through some data creating list items and buttons. I need to pass the button the id the of the item but I am not sure how to string concat.

```
  <% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {%>
     <li><%= data[i].name + " " + data[i].species%> <button onclick="deleteAnimal(data[i]._id)" type="button"> Delete </button></li>
  <% } %>
```

How do I get the `deleteAnimal` function to interpret the actual id value?
Right now the error I get is `data is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

use `<%=` tag:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
   <li><%= data[i].name + " " + data[i].species %><button onclick="deleteAnimal(<%= data[i]._id %>)" type="button"> Delete </button></li>
<% } %>
```

```js
var data = [{ _id: 1 }, { _id: 2 }];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(ejs.render('<button onclick="deleteAnimal(<%= data[i]._id %>)" type="button"> Delete </button>', {
    data: data
  }));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/mde/ejs/releases/download/v2.5.5/ejs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this implementation. I get an error:
view:17 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
view:19 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing ejs variable properly.  You are passing data as normal js variable. 
 Use `<%=data[i]._id %>` for passing to deleteAnimal() function.

```
  <% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {%> <li><%= data[i].name + " " + data[i].species%> <button onclick="deleteAnimal(<%=data[i]._id %>)" type="button"> Delete </button></li> <% } %>
```